# How to download certain folders from url

Tags: bash, scripts, wget

when I use this command:

`wget  -r -np -nH --cut-dirs=6 -R "index.html*" -e robots=off  "https://physionet.org/physiobank/database/challenge/2018/training/"`

It will download all the folders (994 folders) inside `training` folder. If there is a way to edit the command for downloading just certain folders for example the first 50 folders.

The folders are in this order, and inside each one of them there are four files:

```
tr03-0005                                                      
tr03-0029                                                          
tr03-0052                                                          
tr03-0061                                                         
tr03-0078                                                            
tr03-0079                                                            
tr03-0083                                                            
tr03-0086                                                           
tr03-0087                                                      
tr03-0092 
.
. 
.
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `-i` flag, that will read the list of URLs you want to download from a file. So if you have file.txt with this content:

```
https://physionet.org/physiobank/database/challenge/2018/training/tr03-0005                                                      
https://physionet.org/physiobank/database/challenge/2018/training/tr03-0029
```

and use `wget other_options -i file.txt` then you will download just those two, the first two folders. Note that with `-i` you don't need to pass an URL since each URL is going to be read from the file.

Comment: Amazing idea. It works! Thank you.

Comment: You should probably accept the answer then ...

Answer (score 0):

Read `man wget`, and you'll find

```
   -X list
   --exclude-directories=list
       Specify a comma-separated list of directories you wish to exclude from download.
       Elements of list may contain wildcards.
```

Comment: oh damn didn't realize it could wildcard. but can it do ranges?

Comment: If there is EXCLUDE then of course there is INCLUDE I will try them.

Answer (score 0):

Wget has nothing to account for limiting in this manner (that I could remember or find).

But for this specific case you can use the shell to naively parse out the subdirectories up to a limit and grab them individually:

```sh
# Where `n` is the limit we want
n=50; c=0; for f in $(curl https://physionet.org/physiobank/database/challenge/2018/training/ | grep '^<a href="tr' | sed 's/.*"\(.*\)".*/\1/'); do if [ $c -ge $n ]; then break; fi; wget -r -np -nH --cut-dirs=5 -R "index.html*,.mat" -e robots=off "https://physionet.org/physiobank/database/challenge/2018/training/${f}"; c=$(($c + 1)) ; done
```